Generic type inference fails when reordering arguments in function with multiple generic callbacks
I'm implementing a type-safe shapeAdapter function in TypeScript that takes an original object, an adapt function to transform it, and a revert function to convert it back.
function shapeAdapter<Original, Transformed>(props: {
  original: Original;
  adapt: (original: NoInfer<Original>) => Transformed;
  revert: (transformed: NoInfer<Transformed>) => NoInfer<Original>;
}) {
  throw new Error("Implementation does not matter")
}

The function works as expected when adapt is declared before revert:
shapeAdapter({
  original: { value: 1 },
  adapt: (original) => original.value,
  revert: (transformed) => ({ value: transformed }), // transformed is of type number as expected
})

However, when I swap the order of adapt and revert, the type inference breaks:
shapeAdapter({
  original: { value: 1 },
  revert: (transformed) => ({ value: transformed }), // "transformed" is of type unknown! should be number
  adapt: (original) => original.value,
})

In the second example, transformed in the revert function is inferred as unknown instead of number.
I'm using the NoInfer utility type to prevent excessive type widening, but it doesn't solve this issue.
Is there a way to maintain correct type inference regardless of the order of these callbacks?
TypeScript Version: 5.5.2
Playground Link TS Playground
What I tried:
I initially implemented the function with adapt before revert, which worked as expected, but then i attempted to reorder the arguments, placing revert before adapt, but it broke the type inference, then i tried to use the NoInfer utility type on the generic parameters to prevent excessive type widening, but that didn't help either.
What I expected:
I expected TypeScript to be able to infer the relationship between the Original and Transformed types based on the structure of the shapeAdapter function, regardless of the order of the callbacks.

The answer is unfortunately no. TS can only do this at all due to support added in TS 4.7 as implemented in ms/TS#48538. It says "inferred type information only flows from left to right between context sensitive arguments. This is a long standing limitation of our inference algorithm, and one that isn't likely to change." Does that fully address the q? If so, I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Yes, this addresses the question, thanks for the reference

This is unfortunately not (currently) possible. TypeScript has always had problems being able to simultaneously infer both generic type arguments and callback parameter types from context.  There is an open feature request at microsoft/TypeScript#47599 but it will almost certainly never be completely solved for all use cases.
Before TypeScript 4.7 introduced support for inferring generics and callback parameters from object literals, even your working case would break. (You can verify this by replacing NoInfer with your own definition of it, drop it into an IDE running TS4.6, and see for yourself.) The support we do have was implemented in microsoft/TypeScript#48538 and it specifically says that

inferred type information only flows from left to right between context sensitive arguments. This is a long standing limitation of our inference algorithm, and one that isn't likely to change.

"Left to right" means that the order of the properties in your object literal matters when it comes to inference. You want to mention the "known" stuff earlier than anything that needs to be inferred.  This is very similar to how things would behave if you split your object into separate function parameters (inferred type information flows from earlier parameter types to later parameter types):
function shapeAdapterGood<O, T>(
  original: O,
  adapt: (o: NoInfer<O>) => T,
  revert: (t: NoInfer<T>) => NoInfer<O>
) { }
shapeAdapterGood({ value: 1 }, o => o.value, t => ({ value: t }))

function shapeAdapterBad<O, T>(
  original: O,
  revert: (t: NoInfer<T>) => NoInfer<O>,
  adapt: (o: NoInfer<O>) => T
) { }
shapeAdapterBad({ value: 1 }, t => ({ value: t }), o => o.value) // error!

Or how things would behave if you curried the function (type information flows from earlier calls to later calls):
const shapeAdapterCurryGood =
  <O,>(original: O) =>
    <T,>(adapt: (o: NoInfer<O>) => T) =>
      (revert: (t: NoInfer<T>) => NoInfer<O>) => { }

shapeAdapterCurryGood({ value: 1 })(o => o.value)(t => ({ value: t }))

const shapeAdapterCurryBad =
  <O,>(original: O) =>
    <T,>(revert: (t: NoInfer<T>) => NoInfer<O>) =>
      (adapt: (o: NoInfer<O>) => T) => { };

shapeAdapterCurryBad({ value: 1 })(t => ({ value: t }))(o => o.value) // error!

With this last formulation it should be obvious why inference doesn't work; TypeScript would have to somehow delay inference of T until after the second function was called, but by that time it's too late.  Of course you might hope that having things as an object literal would allow TypeScript more leeway to do such inference, but this is not the case. TypeScript mostly is optimized to infer from left to right.
Playground link to code
